# How to show inherited classes in ERD

Tags: inheritance, diagram, erd

[image: ERD Diagram]

I'm trying to create an ERD for the following below system but struggling to link the entities and sub classes, I've looked online but having not done one before i'm finding it hard to piece it together. Any help / guidance would be useful?

So, a Host for the system only manages the policies and procedures and authorise access and doesn't have any link to the EBI or IFR tickets, the customer is an NHS organisation but only can view policies, view list of practices and procedures again no link to IFR or EBI tickets. Now, the Practice admins are administrators for their GP practice they manage accounts within their practice and they can view list of approvals (EBI) download PAT letter (EBI) view and search IFR requests add comments to IFR requests and view the approval/rejection letter for IFR, the same goes for the Provider Admin this could be a local healthcare provider who has the same access levels as a Practice Admin. Moving on to the Panel Viewer can only view a panel doesn't have any decision on the IFR but can view the Panel that will be helping to make that decision on the IFR (no link to EBI) For the Panel Decision Maker they can approve or decline at Panel or request for more information on the IFR. For the referrer this person could be working at the GP practice or Healthcare provider and they refer patients for procedures either by raising an EBI or IFR and they manage the EBI & IFR request for the patient. The IFR team are a group of people who hand the IFR request they can reject the IFR from the get go for being inappropriate for an IFR and they can assign to DM, CSO or Expert they set up a Panel if a Panel is needed and they will notify the referrer if the IFR has been approved or declined. The DM is the person who makes the decision when it is assigned to them they can see the IFRs and view panel and assign to expert. The CSO helps in making the final decision on the IFR so gives their recommendation. The expert is a specialist who provides expert advice on the IFR request. The Panel Viewer, Panel Decision Maker, IFR Team, DM, CSO & Expert are only linked to IFRs in one way or the other with various different levels of access. The referrer can view EBIs and IFRs and raises them is the only person alongside the Practice and Provider admin who are linked to both EBI and IFRs. Now for this ERD I need to show how everything links to the IFR % EFR Tickets

Answer (score 0):

As you're working with ERD, it's about entities and not classes.  Several variants of enhanced ERD (EERD) exist, and allow to represent inheritance.  A popular notation is the [`IsA` relationship](http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/dbms/eermodel.htm).

If you want to stick to classical ERD, you may apply some ORM mapping techniques that express a model that can represent the same relationships, but without explicit inheritance notation.